# Should I put my business invariant check in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC. I need to check duplicated `premises name` before saving premises.
In Controller

```
public void savePremises() {
    // Check duplicate 
    Set<String> premiseNames = new HashSet<String>();
    //premises is global variable which contain the list of premises to save
    for (Premise premise : premises) {
        String premiseName = premise.getPremiseName();
        if (premiseNames.contains(premiseName)) {
            Clients.showNotification("Duplicated primise name "
                    + premiseName);
            return;
        } else {
            premiseNames.add(premiseName);
        }
    }
..............
}
```

Because I will use this checking code for premises in another controller, so I want to put it in service class to reuse later. 

Then I need to return 2 value from service function: 

+ A boolean value to indicate the result of checking.

+ A string value for duplicated premise name. 

 I have a solution that returning null value for premise name to indicate no duplicated premise name. Is it bad practice to do this?
In Controller

```
public void savePremises(){
    String premiseName =premiseService.isDuplicatedPremiseName(premises);
    if( premiseName!=null) {
        Clients.showNotification("Duplicated primise name "
                + premiseName);
        return;
    }
}
```

In Service

```
public String isDuplicatedPremiseName(List<Premise> premises) {
   Set<String> premiseNames = new HashSet<String>();
   for (Premise premise : premises) {
    String premiseName = premise.getPremiseName();
    if (premiseNames.contains(premiseName)) {
        return premiseName;
    } else {
        premiseNames.add(premiseName);
    }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I'd say it is ok. but method name isDuplicatedPremiseName or (isXXX) usually implies that the return type is boolean, so you may want to change the method name to something like retrieveDuplicatedPremiseName?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for your suggestion. I will change the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a solution that returning null value for premise name to indicate no duplicated premise name. Is it bad practice to do this?

Yes, returning null is definitely bad practice.

Instead, you can use [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class that contains value or contains indication that value is not available.

```
public Optional<String> GetFirstDuplicate(List<Premise> premises)
```

> I need to check duplicated premises name before saving premises.

If your business logic doesn't allow duplicates in premise names, you should definitely check for duplication in controller *before* passing these names into business layer.

Exceptions in business layer are used to indicate coder's mistakes, not user's mistakes. Occasionally entering the same name twice is user's mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, Spring MVC controllers should be a very thin adapter from service logic to HTTP (either HTML or a JSON/XML REST API). Besides basic DTO validation, business logic should be contained in your service classes. This makes the business logic easier to test and more reusable (e.g., between controllers that present both HTML and JSON).

In your case, unless the users are actively expecting to search for duplicates (perhaps in a search for public records), it would be better not to explicitly call the checker at all. The business logic should be responsible for ensuring that invariants are preserved and *throw an exception* if not. You can either catch the exception in the controller (usually the case for an HTML controller) or annotate it with Spring HTTP annotations and allow it to propagate (often the case for a JSON controller).

Comment: Sorry for my short explanation above. In my case, the user will enter a list of premises, so maybe the list has duplicated name, I need to tell the user exactly which name it is. So I need to check it before doing any thing such as saving, so the exception would be not ideal. <br/>"The business logic should be responsible for ensuring that invariants are preserved and throw an exception if not" this information would help me later.